# Redirection in asp.net core

Tags: angularjs, typescript, asp.net-core-mvc

In my application mvc 6, asp.net core and when I do the redirection the url in the browser appears to me as below, and the redirection does not happen.

http://localhost:46439/index.html#!/index#%2FInventory%2Fwarehouse%2Flist

url With special characters.

It adds '!' After the # and replace the '/' with '% 2F'

I do not know what the prolme exactly, since I use the visual studio IIS express 2015,

Can you help me please :)

Answer (score 0):

Typically the #! (pronounced hash bang) followed by a path is used by browser based javascript code in single page apps to keep track of where in the single page app the user is.

Anything past the # will not affect which backend web page is requested if the url is sent to the backend web server.  In the case of the url you provided that means that if this url were sent to the server, the page or route to respond would be

```
http://localhost:46439/index.html
```

Does that help?

Can you provide the code that you used to do the redirection?